# Artifical Neural Network Firing Below Threshold

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to build a simple digit recognising ANN circuit using python. It has one input layer with 15 inputs, hidden layer and output layer(10 neurons). I am truly a beginner in this field but i am an experienced programmer.

[image: Neural sample network]

When a=1 and b=0 and I want output f=0 & g=1

```
   Value at:
   C
   1*1+-0.5*0= 1  
   D
   1*0+.1*1 = 0.1
   E
   -1*0+-0.5*1 = -0.5
```

Since the sigmoidal function fires only when value > 0 i guess only neurons C and D fires. So output of E will be 0 right?

C:1  D:0.1  E:0

```
     Value at F:
     1*1+0.1*-0.3+0*0.3=0.97 (neuron fires)
     Value at G:
     1*-1+-0.5*0.1+0*.1=  -1.05  (neuron does not fire)
```

So the output seems to be F:1 & G:0 which is opposite of desired.

Now i am really confused about backpropagation. How can i use backpropagation to correct the weights in this case? The math steps would be great..

Guys i need confirmation whether the math is right. And after that i have lot of supplementary questions i have to ask.

I am using the sigmoidal function for threshold. So if the value is less than 0, there is no output and if greater than 0 then it fires.

### If a neuron does not fire, then its output is taken as zero right?

Comment: Neural networks are no trivial thing. If you really want to learn more look at free online coures like this https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning or book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do but if you only need the math here is a link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network

Comment: i didnt say its a trivial thing...if i get the math right, i have the programming knowledge to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps a bit, although our implementations / approches are different.

In my implementation(small/simple network) I calculate the **output as the sum of all input-nodes-output times the weights**, *in this case if the neuron doesn't fire it doesn't count as input.*
(but in my implementation i let the negative values get passed to the next level)

**Pseudocode**

```
    for (let idxHidden in hiddensOutput) {
        let sum = 0
        for (let idxInput in inputsOutput) {
          sum = sum + inputsOutput[idxInput] * inputsWeight[idxInput][idxHidden];
        }
        hiddensOutput[idxHidden] = sigmoid(sum);
    }
```

> **hiddensOutput** ... is a list of node in the next layer
>   **inputsOutput**  ... is a list of inputs for the nodes of the `hiddensOutputs`
>   **inputsWeight** ... is a matrix of the weights between those nodes (setting this up is the "tricky" part)
>   **hiddensOutput** ... is a list with the inputs for the next layer

So to answer the question: **"If a neuron does not fire, then its output is taken as zero right?"**

<kbd>**Yes**</kbd>

> **Update:**
>
> Here are the links from the comment Section I posted before online
>   course
>
> - http://coursera.org/learn/machine-learning (there are other some even  self  paced)
> - http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do interesting book (with lots of python code [explained])
> - http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network (basic Math)

Comment: my doubt is i am using the sigmoidal function so if the value is 0 or less than 0, then it wont count as input to next layer right? But as i understand, it is up to me whether to give that input or not.? right?

Comment: There are serveral point here(as I understand): My sigmoid function returns a number between 0 and 1. (in rare cases 0 or 1 exact), so there will output. The important part is not the input value it is the weight between the nodes, because in the backpropagation the values will be altered(and by training the network). so an input of 0 in the Feedward -Step is not final, as long as the weight are kept. And Yes it is up to you and your sigmoid function(may last function returned values between negativ infinity an positiv infinity), so i had to pass negative values. :) I hode this helps

Comment: So in this network is it okay to use sigmoid for the hidden and output layer? Ofcourse input layer is 1 or 0 depending on pixels selected or not in digit recognizer? If i have used sigmoid function and calculated all the errors for individual neurons in back propagation, then how do i adjust the weights? whats the formula for that?  Like if I know error for neuron (d) is 0.5..then how do i adjust the weight from d to f.. there is a derviating something like f(b)(1-f(b)) something right? I am not good with calculus can you give a simple equation or example like how to adjust weight from d to f?

Comment: I am sorry Your questions, are too many an broad to anser with a single answer, and even less in the comment section. You should really get a deeper insight into Neural networks and those kind specific to your usage. checkout the links i posted under your question, or checkout some forum. But SO is though for small concise questions, that can be answered in a short fashion. (ps.: in the Book mentioned there is a _complete_ code for an N-network in python, with explanation)